# Highcharts issue with multiple X axes

Tags: highcharts

When I have multiple x axes in a column chart the max value rendered isn't being computed correctly. Also - zooming doesn't work as expected. Here is a jsfiddle showing the issue - https://jsfiddle.net/ermht671/. Does anyone have an example using 2 x axis with Highcharts?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 1.1
  },
  xAxis: [{
    minRange: 1
  }, {
    minRange: 1,
    linkedTo: 0,
    visible: false
  }],
  series: [{
    name: 'series',
    data: [
      [0.1, 0.2],
      [0.7, 0.4],
      [1.3, 0.2]
    ]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    xAxis: 1,
    name: 'MPO',
    data: []
  }],

  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    zoomType: 'x'
  }
});
```

Comment: Please share what you expect both in terms of max value plotted correctly, and zooming.

Comment: I expect the max to be 1.5 in this example - the same as if you remove the 2nd x axis. Zooming should also work as it does without the 2nd x axis. If you zoom in with the example above it doesn't adjust the max x displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to set `chart.alignTicks` to `false`.

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/3098h8vd/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.alignTicks